# How to elegantly configure a Logger with a configuration file while supporting log rotation

Tags: go, go-zap

### Problem Description

- Function: `Test1()` is a log rotation and cutting library `gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2` recommended in the official documentation.
- Function: `Test2()` is a Logger that uses yaml to read configuration based on the basic configuration in the official documentation.

After executing the main function,

in the console output:

`2023-05-15T08:49:16.555+0800 | INFO | logger construction succeeded:config from yaml | {"app": "jpz"}`

in the log file `foo.log` output:

`{"level":"info","ts":1684111756.5545945,"msg":"logger construction succeeded:lumberjack.Logger"}`

These two logs are definitely different.

### My current requirements:

1. Both support using the configuration file `config_log_zap.yaml` so that all configurations can take effect, and let `lumberjack` complete the log rotation and splitting work.
2. The output of both the console and the log file should be the same, so that I can quickly apply the desired content through the configuration file. The reason why both the console and the log file are needed is because I need to pay attention to and record past output messages during development.

   In the console output:

   `2023-05-15T08:49:16.555+0800 | INFO | logger construction succeeded:config from yaml | {"app": "jpz"}`

   In the log file `foo.log` output:

   `2023-05-15T08:49:16.555+0800 | INFO | logger construction succeeded:config from yaml | {"app": "jpz"}`
3. How should I merge `Test1()` and `Test2()` into one function `Test0()` to meet the above two requirements?

Please give me some help, I've been studying it for a long time.

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "os"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
)

func Test1() {
    // lumberjack.Logger is already safe for concurrent use, so we don't need to
    // lock it.
    w := zapcore.AddSync(&lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   "./foo.log",
        MaxSize:    500, // megabytes
        MaxBackups: 3,
        MaxAge:     28, // days
    })
    core := zapcore.NewCore(
        zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()),
        w,
        zap.InfoLevel,
    )
    logger := zap.New(core)
    logger.Info("logger construction succeeded:lumberjack.Logger")
}

func Test2() {
    var cfg zap.Config
    yamlFile, _ := os.ReadFile("./config_log_zap.yaml")
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &cfg); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    logger := zap.Must(cfg.Build())
    defer logger.Sync()

    logger.Info("logger construction succeeded:config from yaml")
}

func main() {
    Test1()
    Test2()
}
```

config_log_zap.yaml

```yaml
# For the full description for the configuration, see
# https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/382e2511e51cda8afde24f9e6e741f934308edfa/config.go#L58-L94
level: 'debug'
development: true
disableCaller: true
disableStacktrace: false
sampling:
  initial: 100
  thereafter: 100
encoding: 'console'
encoderConfig:
  messageKey: 'msg'
  levelKey: 'level'
  timeKey: 'ts'
  nameKey: 'logger'
  callerKey: 'caller'
  functionKey: 'function'
  stacktraceKey: 'stacktrace'
  skipLineEnding: false
  lineEnding: "\n"
  levelEncoder: 'capital'
  timeEncoder: 'iso8601'
  durationEncoder: 'string'
  callerEncoder: 'full'
  nameEncoder: 'full'
  consoleSeparator: ' | '
outputPaths:
  - 'stdout'
  - './foo.log'
errorOutputPaths:
  - 'stderr'
  - './error_logs'
initialFields:
  app: 'jpz'
```

Comment: zap.ReplaceGlobals(logger) https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/master/global.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [zap.RegisterSink](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#RegisterSink) to register the `lumberjack` logger as a new sink:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
)

type lumberjackSink struct {
    lumberjack.Logger
}

func (l *lumberjackSink) Sync() error {
    return nil
}

func parseNumber(s string, fallback int) int {
    v, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err == nil {
        return v
    }
    return fallback
}

func Test0() {
    if err := zap.RegisterSink("lumberjack", func(u *url.URL) (zap.Sink, error) {
        // Read parameters from URL:
        // lumberjack://localhost/foo.log?maxSize=500&maxBackups=3&maxAge=28
        filename := strings.TrimLeft(u.Path, "/")
        if filename == "" {
            filename = "foo.log"
        }
        q := u.Query()
        l := &lumberjackSink{
            Logger: lumberjack.Logger{
                Filename:   filename,
                MaxSize:    parseNumber(q.Get("maxSize"), 500),
                MaxBackups: parseNumber(q.Get("maxBackups"), 3),
                MaxAge:     parseNumber(q.Get("maxAge"), 28),
            },
        }
        return l, nil
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var cfg zap.Config
    yamlFile, _ := os.ReadFile("./config_log_zap.yaml")
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &cfg); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    logger := zap.Must(cfg.Build())
    defer logger.Sync()

    logger.Info("logger construction succeeded:config from yaml")
}

func main() {
    Test0()
}
```

And modify the config file to set `outputPaths` like this:

```yaml
outputPaths:
  - stdout
  - lumberjack://localhost/foo.log?maxSize=500&maxBackups=3&maxAge=28
```

Comment: The `outputPaths` configuration is simply too subtle. Take a good look at your answers. Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: Yeah, I found `zap.RegisterSink` first. And its source code leads me to `outputPath`. Thanks for the feedback!